# Do the birds who perch in the mustard tree have allegorical meaning?

Tags: matthew, parables

In Matthew 13:31-32, Jesus tells the Parable of the Mustard Seed (NIV):

> He told them another parable: "The kingdom of heaven is like a mustard seed, which a man took and planted in his field. Though it is the smallest of all seeds, yet when it grows, it is the largest of garden plants and becomes a tree, so that the birds come and perch in its branches."

Obviously one of the points of the parable is that while the mustard seed has a small beginning, it ends with a surprisingly large effect. This matches the theme of the immediately following Parable of the Yeast.

However, in the Mustard Seed parable Jesus also mentions that birds come and perch in the tree's branches. A couple commentators, drawing on images of birds in Ezekiel, seem to see an allegory to the Gentile inclusion. Others insist that this is strictly a one-point parable and that the birds carry no additional allegorical meaning. But recently I heard it suggested there might be a connection to the birds in the Parable of the Sower just a little before this passage:

> As he was scattering the seed, some fell along the path, and the birds came and ate it up.

Beyond only the verbal connection, I don't know how such a connection is supposed to work, though. Is anyone aware of interpreters who follow such a line of thought, and if so, how does it work? And finally, is there any weight to it? Or should we see a reference to Gentile inclusion here? Or are the birds just there to aid with the visual of a big plant from a small seed?

Answer (score 5):

> *But recently I heard it suggested there might be a connection to the birds in the Parable of the Sower just a little before this passage*

The way the parable is phrased doesn't lend itself to any negative allegorical interpretation of the birds. The concept of nesting under protection is hard to square with any link to the birds in the parable of the soils:

> <sup>32</sup>It is the smallest of all seeds, but when it has grown it is larger than all the garden plants and becomes a tree, so that ***the birds of the air come and make nests in its branches***.” <sub><sub>[13:32, ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/mat13.32)</sub></sub>

The expression `τὰ πετεινὰ τοῦ οὐρανοῦ` appears in elsewhere in Matthew, only with a positive (or at worst, neutral) connotation:

> <sup>26</sup>Look at ***the birds of the air***: they neither sow nor reap nor gather into barns, and yet your heavenly Father feeds them. Are you not of more value than they? <sub><sub>[6:26, ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/mat6.26)</sub></sub>
>
> <sup>20</sup>And Jesus said to him, “Foxes have holes, and ***birds of the air*** have nests, but the Son of Man has nowhere to lay his head.” <sub><sub>[8:20, ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/mat8.20)</sub></sub>

> *Or should we see a reference to Gentile inclusion here? Or are the birds just there to aid with the visual of a big plant from a small seed?*

A link to Gentile inclusion here is too great a leap to make with any confidence<sup><sup>[1]</sup></sup>. Rather, the parable makes a particular point of *visible*, *relative* size<sup><sup>[2]</sup></sup>. It is "a *grain* of mustard seed" starting as "the *smallest* of all seeds", then finally it is "*larger* than all the garden plants". The relative size is visually emphasised by the fact that birds are able to "come and make nests in its branches", in contrast to the other "garden plants".

---

<sub><sup>[1]</sup> Gentile inclusion isn't a theme of the other parables, and is only slightly alluded to in Matthew's gospel until the latter chapters.</sub>

<sub><sup>[2]</sup> In contrast to the parable of the yeast that follows, which continues the theme of growth.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Throughout the seven kingdom parables in Matthew 13, Jesus seems to be using similar words and metaphors within the parables:

```
Element     Parable
Sow         Sower/Tares/Mustard Seed
Sower       Sower/Tares
Wicked One  Sower/Tares/Net
Birds       Sower/Mustard Seed
Field       Tares/Mustard Seed/Treasure
```

In His explanations, Jesus explains certain metaphors. For example, in the parable of the Sower the Word is sown. In the explanation of the Tares, He identifies the Sower as the Son of Man, but what is sown is not identified. Yet from the parable and explanation it is clear that what is sown is the Word.

In the parable of the Tares, the field is the earth and it appears to represent the earth elsewhere. Likewise for the wicked one. Apparently in this group of parables Jesus does not vary a metaphor between parables.

If that is the case, then birds are identified in the parable of the Sower (ESV):

> *And as he sowed, some seeds fell along the path, and the birds came and devoured them. (13:4)*
>
> *When anyone hears the word of the kingdom and does not understand it, the evil one comes and snatches away what has been sown in his heart. This is what was sown along the path. (13:20-21)*

The birds are affiliated with the evil one and it is unlikely they are meant to have a positive meaning such as the Gentile inclusion, in the parable of the Mustard Seed.

The explanation of the Sower states the seed sown on the path which the birds devoured represents the Word which was sown but was not understood. Therefore the birds did not prevent the Word from reaching a person; instead the prevented a person from understanding the Word.

The parable of the Mustard Seed differs from the parable of the Sower on two key points. The sower is a "man" not a "sower" and the mustard seed is not the Word. This is evident because it is identified differently (a mustard seed) and it does not grow or produce like the Word (as described in either the Sower or Tares parables).

Birds make noise. A tree full of birds would be a noisy place. The imagery of the parable of the Mustard Seed is one a plant which has grown out of proportion into a tree providing a place for a lot birds to nest and make a lot of noise.

In the parable of the Mustard Seed, a seed which is not the Word grows up out of proportion and provides a place for the birds to nest. The seed could represent human wisdom or false teaching. If the role of the birds from the Sower is continued into the Mustard Seed parable, the birds continue to prevent understanding of the Word. They are making noise which hinders, distorts, or denies a person the opportunity to understand the Word. Their noise would also draw attention to the "impressive" tree where they nest.

Comment: So if "the kingdom of heaven is like a mustard seed" and the "seed could represent human wisdom or false teaching", you're saying that Jesus is claiming that the kingdom of heaven is like a false teaching?

Comment: It is not that the kingdom of heaven is like false teaching but false teaching is present within the kingdom (isn't that true?). Many of the parables teach both good and evil are present.  The enemy plants false seeds which are permitted to grow. The kingdom of heaven is not presented as an always perfect or ideal place. In terms of the Mustard seed, there are 2 other parables with seed. In one there is only good seed; in the other both good and bad. I see no reason why this one could not be about only bad seed.

Answer (score 2):

Birds, elsewhere rendered fowls of the sky or air, largely in the old testament, when used as an allegory refer to both evil and righteous angels, depending on context.

In Matthew 13:31-32, He clearly identifies these birds/fowls as the ''evil one,'' the evil one being a characterisation of a category of them, just as He says the word of God is the seed. Therefore, if we take the signification of that seed to refer to the word of God, so should we understand the birds as the evil ones, most likely the ones in 'high places' so signified in Ephesians 6:12, or the servants of 'the ruler of the air'

> Ephesians 2:2;
>   ..in which you used to walk when you conformed to the ways of this world and of **the ruler of the power of the air**, the spirit who is now at work in the sons of disobedience.

The birds would be the 'powers' of the air.

In Ecclestiate, we are warned not to speak a word against  the 'king,' even in the secret, because these 'rational' birds/fowls may 'hear' the complaint and inform the king, and according to the context, it doesn't refer to a man but the prince of darkness, since these 'birds' don't serve man but fellow higher up spirit rulers in Ephesians 2.

> Ecclesiastes 10:20
>   Curse not the king, no not even in your thought; and curse not the rich in your bedchamber: for **a bird of the air** shall carry the voice, and that which has wings shall tell the matter.

Strangely, it's same warning that Jude 1:9 gives!

So in many places where this symbolism of ''birds'' is used, it largely concerns how information is handled among men, for evil or for good.
These are the same evil angels in Jeremiah 12:9, denoted as ''speckled birds,' that came as judgements against Israel; which ate Israel's 'fruit,' that is, a 
righteousness derived from observing His laws.

Lastly, but not the least, the signified 'clean, or unclean birds' in the laws whose ways Israel shouldn't practice, this signified as 'not eating,' the same 'eating' signified in John 6:56 as 'if you eat my flesh and...'' , meaning to practice His words.
This is the allogory of birds in most parts of scripture.

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be an allusion to Ezekiel 17:

> NIV Ezek 17: 22“ ‘This is what the Sovereign Lord says: I myself will
>   take a shoot from the very top of a cedar and plant it; I will break
>   off a tender sprig from its topmost shoots and plant it on a high and
>   lofty mountain. 23On the mountain heights of Israel I will plant it;
>   it will produce branches and bear fruit and become a splendid cedar.
>   **Birds of every kind will nest in it; they will find shelter in the shade of its branches.** 24All the trees of the forest will know that
>   I the Lord bring down the tall tree and make the low tree grow tall. I
>   dry up the green tree and make the dry tree flourish. “ ‘I the Lord
>   have spoken, and I will do it.’ ”

In Ezekiel 31 the tree shelters beasts and birds and they seems to be associated with nations:

> NIV Ezek 31: 3Consider Assyria, once a cedar in Lebanon, with
>   beautiful branches overshadowing the forest; it towered on high, its
>   top above the thick foliage. 4The waters nourished it, deep springs
>   made it grow tall; their streams flowed all around its base and sent
>   their channels to all the trees of the field.
>   **5So it towered higher than all the trees of the field; its boughs increased and its branches grew long, spreading because of abundant
>   waters. 6All the birds of the sky nested in its boughs, all the
>   animals of the wild gave birth under its branches; all the great
>   nations lived in its shade.** 7It was majestic in beauty, with its
>   spreading boughs, for its roots went down to abundant waters. 8The
>   cedars in the garden of God could not rival it, nor could the junipers
>   equal its boughs, nor could the plane trees compare with its branches—
>   no tree in the garden of God could match its beauty. 9I made it
>   beautiful with abundant branches, the envy of all the trees of Eden in
>   the garden of God.

A comparison can be drawn with the United States military presence throughout the world discouraging aggression by its enemies and providing a certain *Pax America*, the birds and beasts being the nations "shaded" by the "branches" of the empire.

Jesus draws on that and says that the kingdom of heaven(s) will likewise rule the nations with a rod of iron. But the image is much more profound than most people grasp because he doesn't say that a small tree becomes a great tree but rather that a small seed is planted/buried and THEN grows into a huge tree. Jesus is the small mustard seed and he dies and is resurrected:

> NIV John 12: 23Jesus replied, “The hour has come for the Son of Man to
>   **be glorified**. 24Very truly I tell you, **unless a kernel of wheat falls to the ground and dies, it remains only a single seed. But if it
>   dies, it produces many seeds.** 25Anyone who loves their life will
>   lose it, while anyone who hates their life in this world will keep it
>   for eternal life. 26Whoever serves me must follow me; and where I am,
>   my servant also will be. My Father will honor the one who serves me.
>   27“Now my soul is troubled, and what shall I say? ‘Father, save me
>   from this hour’? No, it was for this very reason I came to this hour.
>   28Father, glorify your name!” Then a voice came from heaven, “I have
>   glorified it, and will glorify it again.” 29The crowd that was there
>   and heard it said it had thundered; others said an angel had spoken to
>   him. 30Jesus said, “This voice was for your benefit, not mine. **31Now
>   is the time for judgment on this world; now the prince of this world
>   will be driven out. 32And I, when I am lifted upg from the earth, will
>   draw all people to myself.” 33He said this to show the kind of death
>   he was going to die.**

The "many seeds" shows that believers are planted/buried with Jesus:

> NIV Romans 6: 3Or don’t you know that all of us who were baptized into
>   Christ Jesus were baptized into his death? 4We were therefore buried
>   [ie: "planted"] with him through baptism into death in order that,
>   just as Christ was raised from the dead through the glory of the
>   Father, we too may live a new life. 5For if we have been united with
>   him in a death like his, we will certainly also be united with him in
>   a resurrection like his.

So the believers are not the birds but rather the branches:

> NIV John 15: 3Or don’t you know that all of us who were baptized into
>   Christ Jesus were baptized into his death? 4We were therefore buried
>   with him through baptism into death in order that, just as Christ was
>   raised from the dead through the glory of the Father, we too may live
>   a new life. 5For if we have been united with him in a death like his,
>   we will certainly also be united with him in a resurrection like his.

So the story of the kingdom that Jesus is providing is:

- Jesus is the mustard seed
- God planted him in his field in his death
- God raised Jesus from the dead to rule the nations with a rod of iron
- believers are planted in the pattern of his death
- they are co-raised with him through the operation of God
- this new regime is the king and his subjects
- there is some sense in which the kingdom of God is a superpower over the whole earth, which will be fully realized after the tree grows and matures
- the birds are the nations that live in the enforced peace
- this is fully realized in the millennium

But in the final eschaton, God alone rules and the enforced peace is replaced with a true peace where only the people of God live in true peace and harmony forever. Until that day the foxes have holes to live in and birds of the air have nests while the son of man and the saints are not at home except in the kingdom and rule of God.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase in Matthew 13:32 is literally "birds of the sky", not simply "birds" as the NIV suggests.  The Greek word for "sky" (οὐρανός), can also mean "heaven".  The root of the word for "bird" (πετεινόν) is the verb πέτομαι, which means "to fly".  Hence "birds of the sky" can also mean something like "winged creatures of heaven".

Theophylact, a Byzantine commentator, suggests that the birds of the last verse could represent angels:

> Thus you will be come greater than the shrubs, that is, greater than
>   those who are weak and imperfect, by yourself being perfect, so that
>   even the winged creatures of heave, that is, the angels, will take
>   their rest in you who are living the angelic life
>
> *Explanation of the Gospel According to Matthew* (tr. Chrysostom Press, p. 116).

Answer (score 1):

It has always seemed to me that the birds have represented the ability for demonic influences existing within the church kingdom.  I have never heard it supposed that these could be holy angels as well.  I looked up this interpretation because this is how I read it being so close the parable of the sowers and I do not think this is a coincidence.  I definately dont think Jesus mentioned the birds for no particular reason.
Practicly I think this way because it seems that in all congregations there seems to be elemental spirits at work which constantly need to be recognized and dealt with accordingly.  It partially comes from my struggle in how to reconcile how many of the churches I have been to seem to have people who love and worship Jesus in Spirit and truth yet there also exists erroneous doctrine and love for the world....just sayin:/

Comment: Welcome to BHSE! Please make sure you take our Tour; see below left.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Do the birds who perch in the mustard tree have allegorical meaning?**

Matthew 13:31-32  (NRSV)

**The Parable of the Mustard Seed**

> 31 "He put before them another parable: “The kingdom of heaven is like
>   a mustard seed that someone took and sowed in his field; 32 it is the
>   smallest of all the seeds, but when it has grown it is the greatest of
>   shrubs and becomes a tree, so that the birds of the air come and make
>   nests in its branches.”

The grain represents the good news of the kingdom of God, and the consequence from the preaching , was the creation of the Christian congregations.

Luke 4:43  (NRSV)

> 43 But he said to them, “I must proclaim the good news of the kingdom
>   of God to the other cities also; for I was sent for this purpose.

The mustard seed was one the tiniest then known, likewise the Christian congregation had a tiny beginning at the time when Jesus was resurrected. But within three to four decades , Paul was very happy to say that the gospel was **proclaimed in all creation:**

Colossians 1:23  (NASB)

> " If indeed you continue in the faith firmly established and
>   steadfast, and not moved away from the hope of the gospel that you
>   have heard, which was **proclaimed in all creation under heaven,** and of
>   which I, Paul, was made a minister."

The growth was rapid so that the "birds of the air ",were able to make,"nests in its branches.” The birds represents the ,humble,  those seeking righteousness,  spiritual food and shelter within the Christian congregation. Compare Ezekiel 17:22-23 and Zephaniah 2:3

Zephaniah 2:3  (NRSV)

> 3 Seek the Lord, all you humble of the land, who do his commands; seek
>   righteousness, seek humility;  perhaps you may be hidden on the day of
>   the Lord’s wrath.

Ezekiel 17:22-23  (NASB)

> 22 Thus says the Lord God, “I will also take a sprig from the lofty
>   top of the cedar and set it out; I will pluck from the topmost of its
>   young twigs a tender one and I will plant it on a high and lofty
>   mountain. 23 On the high mountain of Israel I will plant it, that it
>   may bring forth boughs and bear fruit and become a stately cedar. And
>   birds of every kind will nest under it; they will nest in the shade of
>   its branches.

Answer (score 0):

The birds could refer to the powers of the air in Ephesians 6.
It was the birds that stole the seeds sown by the sower and the birds that hide in the tree.
Satan steals the seeds sown and demons hide within the church bringing in false doctrine. All clean birds nested on the ground and all unclean birds nested in trees more or less.
It was a stork(unclean bird) that took the basket with the woman in the ephah to shinar(Babylon)Zechariah 5v5
Parables with birds indicate demons working against the word of god.

Answer (score 0):

Peace.

Yes, the birds are allegorical.  Specifically, they symbolize the words that swiftly “fly” out of the mouths of people.  Once words are spoken, they are “out” there in the air flying….and you can’t bring them back so to speak.  Think about how “Twitter” is represented by a bird.  A person “tweets” words for all to see.

In Ecclesiastes 10:20,  it says to not curse the king in our own thoughts nor to curse the rich in our “bedchamber”…in the inner man.   Once we have  thoughts, there is a chance that we may speak words vocalizing our inner thoughts in the air.

A “bird of the air”….words….shall carry our inner voice out for others to hear making our thoughts known.  When others hear our words, they may repeat what we say…which can get us in trouble very quickly.

The words swiftly fly to other’s ears who can then  quickly repeat it.   That “which has wings”…the master of wings….the one that hears our words and possesses them….can then go and tell the matter to another that which we have said about them.

> Ecclesiastes 10:20 KJV (20)  *Curse not the king, no not in thy
>   thought; and curse not the rich in thy bedchamber: **for a bird of the
>   air shall carry the voice,** and that which hath wings shall tell the
>   matter.*

A servant of the king of Syria suggested that Elisha was telling the king of Israel the WORDS that the king was thinking/speaking inside (the “bedchamber”).

> 2 Kings 6:11-12 KJV (11)  *Therefore the heart of the king of Syria was
>   sore troubled for this thing; and he called his servants, and said
>   unto them, Will ye not shew me which of us is for the king of Israel?
>   (12)  And one of his servants said, None, my lord, O king: but Elisha,
>   the prophet that is in Israel, **telleth the king of Israel the words
>   that thou speakest in thy bedchamber***.

The “fowls” that come and devour the seeds fallen by the way side are the words of wrath spoken by people who will hear the Word of God spoken in Truth to them and will not agree with what they hear. They will not believe it as it will not align with their own interpretations.   Their own evil words  (the “birds “) spoken in wrath devour it up so that they cannot understand.

> Matthew 13:3-4 KJV (3)  *And he spake many things unto them in
>   parables, saying, Behold, a sower went forth to sow; (4)  **And when he
>   sowed, some seeds fell by the way side, and the fowls came and
>   devoured them up:***

Those who have ears to hear are to hear….and not speak…when one hears the Word of God spoken in the Spirit of Truth.  We must be quick to hear and slow to speak and slow to wrath….or the “birds” of the air (words) fly out of our mouths and devour what we hear.

> Matthew 13:9 KJV (9)  Who hath ears to hear, let him hear.

We are take heed on how we hear in order to enter in to know more.  Whosoever has not, from him shall be taken even that which he seemed to have.   We must have faith.

> Luke 8:18 KJV (18)  ***Take heed therefore how ye hear: for whosoever
>   hath, to him shall be given; and whosoever hath not, from him shall be
>   taken even that which he seemeth to have.***

Those who would come unto Him to understand (desiring to “see” or know Him) cannot because of the “press”… a throng….a multitude of words that will come out of their mouths…. when they hear the Word of God spoken in Christ.

> (19)  *Then came to him his mother and his brethren, and could not
>   come at him for the press.*

They “stand outside” of His knowledge and will not be able to enter in to know His knowledge because of the multitude of words that will prevent them from doing so.

> (20)  And it was told him by certain which said, Thy mother and thy
>   brethren stand without, desiring to see thee.

Only those who hear the Word of God and do it show that they know Him.

> (21)  And he answered and said unto them, My mother and my brethren
>   are these which hear the word of God, and do it.

The first group in Matthew 13 to hear the seed ….the Word of God spoken in truth… becomes full of wrath and speaks a multitude of words in wrath in contention of what they hear.  They do not receive His Word with joy but with wrath and therefore cannot enter in to understand.   What was sown in their heart gets caught away.

> Matthew 13:18-19 KJV (18)  *Hear ye therefore the parable of the sower.
>   (19)  When any one heareth the word of the kingdom, and understandeth
>   it not, then cometh the wicked one, and catcheth away that which was
>   sown in his heart. This is he which received seed by the way side*.

They do not receive it (it fell by the way side) and the birds came….the evil multitude of words came out of their mouths…and devoured the seed…the Word.  It was quickly removed by their contentious words.

> Matthew 13:3-4 KJV (3)  And he spake many things unto them in
>   parables, saying, Behold, a sower went forth to sow; (4)  And when he
>   sowed, some seeds fell by the way side, **and the fowls came and
>   devoured them up**:

In Genesis 40, we see in the chief baker an example of those who will not rejoice in the Bread of Heaven spoken to them in the day of resurrection (the three days).

The three white baskets of the Bread of Heaven was upon his head.  He heard it as the Lord comes to open up our minds to the Scriptures so that we may show that we know God in our response to what we hear.   It was on his head as it was heard and was on his mind….yet he did not receive it.

> Genesis 40: (16)  *When the chief baker saw that the interpretation was
>   good, he said unto Joseph, I also was in my dream, and, behold, I had
>   three white baskets on my head:*

What should have been presented to the Father in Heaven….the rejoicing and praise and thanksgiving for the Bread of Heaven….was “eaten” by the “birds” out of the basket upon his head.

The “birds” again signify the evil words that come (fly through the air) out of the mouth and devour what was heard so that the “baker” (the angry person) will not understand.

Some will hear His voice as He interprets the Scriptures (the Bread of Heaven…the Word of God spoken in the Spirit of truth) and will speak evil in their wrath and disbelief of what they hear.  Even what they will have heard will be taken away from them as they will not enter into His understanding.

> (17)  ***And in the uppermost basket there was of all manner of bakemeats
>   for Pharaoh; and the birds did eat them out of the basket upon my
>   head.*** (18)  And Joseph answered and said, This is the interpretation
>   thereof: The three baskets are three days:

In the Day of Judgment, the wicked shall not understand as the Pharaoh lifted upon the chief baker’s head from off of him.  The head is where the mind is and the wicked shall not understand as they will not hold the mind of Christ towards what they hear.

Their judgment shall be final as the chief baker was hung on a tree (firmness).  The birds shall eat the flesh of the wicked from off them as they shall die in their sins…their evil words.

In other words, the evil words that will fly out of the mouths of the wicked will come back upon them and defile their own mortal bodies until they perish from off this earth.  What comes out of the mouth  (words) defiles the mortal body….the “man”.   Some “birds” are clean and others are unclean.

> (19)  ***Yet within three days shall Pharaoh lift up thy head from off
>   thee, and shall hang thee on a tree; and the birds shall eat thy flesh
>   from off thee.*** (20)  And it came to pass the third day, which was
>   Pharaoh's birthday, that he made a feast unto all his servants: and he
>   lifted up the head of the chief butler and of the chief baker among
>   his servants.

The “butler” or cup bearer will rejoice (the new wine of the Truth gladdens the heart) and will give thanks and praise unto the Lord for His Word of Truth.   He gave the cup into Pharaoh’s hand.

> (21)  *And he restored the chief butler unto his butlership again; and
>   he gave the cup into Pharaoh's hand: (22)  But he hanged the chief
>   baker: as Joseph had interpreted to them*.

The “fowls that fly in the midst of heaven (air)” in Revelation 19 are the evil, multitude of words that people will speak at the hearing of the revealed Word of God in this coming time.  The multitude of words of those who speak them in their wrath shall devour their mortal flesh as they shall perish in their sins….their evil speaking….in the Day of Judgment.

> Revelation 19:17-18 KJV (17)  *And I saw an angel standing in the sun;
>   and he cried with a loud voice, **saying to all the fowls that fly in
>   the midst of heaven, Come and gather yourselves together unto the
>   supper of the great God; (18)  That ye may eat the flesh of kings, and
>   the flesh of captains, and the flesh of mighty men, and the flesh of
>   horses, and of them that sit on them, and the flesh of all men, both
>   free and bond, both small and great***.

By our words shall we be justified and by our words shall we be condemned in the Day of Judgment as every idle word that men shall speak, they shall  give an account thereof in that Day.

> Matthew 12:33-37 KJV (33)  Either make the tree good, and his fruit
>   good; or else make the tree corrupt, and his fruit corrupt: for the
>   tree is known by his fruit. (34)  O generation of vipers, how can ye,
>   being evil, speak good things? for out of the abundance of the heart
>   the mouth speaketh. (35)  A good man out of the good treasure of the
>   heart bringeth forth good things: and an evil man out of the evil
>   treasure bringeth forth evil things. (36)  **But I say unto you, That
>   every idle word that men shall speak, they shall give account thereof
>   in the day of judgment. (37)  For by thy words thou shalt be
>   justified, and by thy words thou shalt be condemned**.

All of which brings us now to the parable of the mustard seed.  The “birds of the air” come and lodge in the branches in the fullness of the kingdom of Heaven….that is, in the Day of Judgment at the end of the age.   The words lodge in the branches thereof indicates the Day of Judgment upon the words of men….whether good or bad towards hearing the Word of the kingdom.

> Matthew 13:31-32 KJV (31)  *Another parable put he forth unto them,
>   saying, The kingdom of heaven is like to a grain of mustard seed,
>   which a man took, and sowed in his field: (32)  Which indeed is the
>   least of all seeds: but when it is grown, it is the greatest among
>   herbs, and becometh a tree, so that the birds of the air come and
>   lodge in the branches thereof.*

Again, Every idle word that men shall speak when they hear the Word spoken from Heaven shall give an account thereof in the Day of Judgment.

> Matthew 12:36-37 KJV (36)  But I say unto you, That every idle word
>   that men shall speak, they shall give account thereof in the day of
>   judgment. (37)  For by thy words thou shalt be justified, and by thy
>   words thou shalt be condemned.

We are the branches and our words are the “birds” that occupy/lodge in our tongues.  Every branch that does not bear fruit is taken away.

> John 15:1-7 KJV (1)  I am the true vine, and my Father is the
>   husbandman. (2)  **Every branch in me that beareth not fruit he taketh
>   away:** and every branch that beareth fruit, he purgeth it, that it may
>   bring forth more fruit. (3)  Now ye are clean through the word which I
>   have spoken unto you. (4)  Abide in me, and I in you. As the branch
>   cannot bear fruit of itself, except it abide in the vine; no more can
>   ye, except ye abide in me. (5)  I am the vine, ye are the branches: He
>   that abideth in me, and I in him, the same bringeth forth much fruit:
>   for without me ye can do nothing. (6)  If a man abide not in me, he is
>   cast forth as a branch, and is withered; and men gather them, and cast
>   them into the fire, and they are burned. (7)  If ye abide in me, and
>   my words abide in you, ye shall ask what ye will, and it shall be done
>   unto you.

Answer (score -1):

### In the The Parable of the Sower Explained

**Mark 4:13 NKJV**

> 13 And He said to them, “Do you not understand this parable? How then will you understand all the parables?

We can see that he is setting the legend for his metaphors within the parable of the sower and he is saying that if we can recognize them we can realize what every parable is saying.

### The Birds

**Mark 4:4 NKJV**

> 4 And it happened, as he sowed, that some seed fell by the **wayside**; and **the birds** of the air came and devoured it.

Here we can see that the metaphor variable "the birds" occurs within the  "wayside" class.

**Mark 4:15 NKJV (Within Section: The Parable of the Sower Explained)**

> 15 And these are the ones by the **wayside** where the word is sown. When they hear, **Satan** comes immediately and takes away the word that was sown in their hearts.

### The Mustard Seed Parable

**Matthew 13:31-32 NKJV (Metaphor Variable Substitution)**

> 31 Another parable He put forth to them, saying: “The kingdom of heaven is like a mustard seed, which a man took and sowed in his field, 32 which indeed is the least of all the seeds; but when it is grown it is greater than the herbs and becomes a tree, so that **Satan** come and nest in its branches.”

### Why This Is Positive?

The important part to see is that Satan is not eating the seed but nesting.

**Mark 4:4 NKJV**

> 4 And it happened, as he sowed, that some seed fell by the wayside; and **the birds** of the air **came and devoured it**.

**Mark 4:15 NKJV (Within Section: The Parable of the Sower Explained)**

> 15 And these are the ones by the **wayside** where the word is sown. When they hear, Satan comes immediately and **takes away the word that was sown in their hearts**.

### First Conclusion

If the birds are resting, they do not take away the word that was sown in the heart.

### The Seed

**Mark 4:3-4a NKJV**

> 3 “Listen! Behold, a sower went out to **sow**. 4 And it happened, as he **sowed**, that some **seed** fell by the wayside; ...

**Mark 4:14-15a NKJV (Within Section: The Parable of the Sower Explained)**

> 14 The sower **sows the word**. 15 And these are the ones by the wayside where the **word is sown**. When they hear ...

Here we can see that the metaphor variable "seed" equals "the word".

**Matthew 13:31-32 NKJV (Metaphor Variable Substitution)**

> 31 Another parable He put forth to them, saying: “The kingdom of heaven is like a mustard **word**, which a man took and sowed in his field, 32 which indeed is the least of all the **words**; but when it is grown it is greater than the herbs and becomes a tree, so that Satan come and nest in its branches.”

If I was overly literal I could say that the word "mustard" does this wonderful stuff, but mustard seeds are types of seeds, likewise "type of word".

**Matthew 13:31-32 NKJV (Metaphor Variable Substitution)**

> 31 Another parable He put forth to them, saying: “The kingdom of heaven is like a **type of word**, which a man took and sowed in his field, 32 which indeed is the least of all the **words**; but when it is grown it is greater than the herbs and becomes a tree, so that Satan come and nest in its branches.”

Comment: Your "metaphor substitutions" seem rather unjustified.